# Need history of Facebook posts done from FirstViewController to SecondViewController in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, uitableview, ios6

I have a dialog box using the native Facebook integration from iOS 6 in my first view controller. I want a history of all the posts made on the first view controller to be in my second view controller, in a `UITableViewCell`. But I haven’t been able to figure out how to interlink the two of them so it can get the feed.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 8;
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        if (cell==nil) {

        }

    if (FBNativeDialogResultSucceeded) {

    cell.textLabel.text=@"someone posted on facebook";
    }

    return cell; 

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can code a notification in  secondviewcontroller. if post in firstviewcontroller complete,then post notification.Secondviewcontroller recived notification ,theb tableview in secondviewcontroller reloaddata.